# reorganizing pytests or pytest output to be more intuitive

Tags: python, testing, pycharm, pytest

I have a general framework for testing various models against a several dataset for which I know the expected results.

A mockup of my current code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,9)],scope='session')
def model_output(request):
    data,expected_results = request.param
    results = data*data
    return results, expected_results

class TestCat1:
    def test_a(self,model_output):
        results, expected_results = model_output
        var = results
        var_truth = expected_results
        if var_truth is None:
            pytest.skip("variable not defined")
        else:
            assert np.allclose(var,var_truth)

    def test_b(self,model_output):
        results, expected_results = model_output
        var = results
        var_truth = expected_results
        if var_truth is None:
            pytest.skip("variable not defined")
        else:
            assert np.allclose(var,var_truth)

    def test_c(self,model_output):
        results, expected_results = model_output
        var = results
        var_truth = expected_results
        if var_truth is None:
            pytest.skip("variable not defined")
        else:
            assert np.allclose(var,var_truth)


class TestCat2:
    def test_d(self,model_output):
        results, expected_results = model_output
        var = results
        var_truth = expected_results
        if var_truth is None:
            pytest.skip("variable not defined")
        else:
            assert np.allclose(var,var_truth)

    def test_e(self,model_output):
        results, expected_results = model_output
        var = results
        var_truth = expected_results
        if var_truth is None:
            pytest.skip("variable not defined")
        else:
            assert np.allclose(var,var_truth)

class TestCat3:
    def test_f(self,model_output):
        results, expected_results = model_output
        var = results
        var_truth = expected_results
        if var_truth is None:
            pytest.skip("variable not defined")
        else:
            assert np.allclose(var,var_truth)
```

So the model is run with each example and the relevant output is stored and compared to the expected results and evaluated if the expected output is defined (otherwise the test is skipped).

My problem is that the output I get from pytest is not very easy to read, and I am wondering what the best way to change it might be. Here is an example of what the output might look like in pycharm:

[Pytest result in pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJpDB.png)

The problem here is basically the way the tests are grouped. It runs all tests for one dataset, before moving on to the next dataset, which is sensible, unfortunately the report at the end reflects this and I end up with all these duplicate categories, where I can't see which dataset has failed unless I expand all the way in (In this mockup I only have a few tests and 3 datasets, but imagine I have 20 datasets and 20 tests). Is there any way to group these tests? I am guessing pytest has some sort of grouping command which I could modify probably in a conftest.py file, but my look at the conftest documentation haven't made me any wiser about this.

Alternatively I'm guessing that I could somehow try to reorder the way the tests are run. I am somewhat hessitant to do this, since the current approach seems more sensible, where each dataset is used in all the tests before moving on to the next. The alternative would require caching or rerunning the model on all the datasets for each test as far as I can see.

It should be noted that I also tried to look at the output when run through CLI, but that didn't seem much better.